# ImmutableJS Typescript Implementation problems

Tags: typescript, redux, immutable.js

[image: immutableJSMap]

I'm struggling to figure out how i would define the "Type" of my data structure here, if anyone could help i'd greatly appreciate it.

Basically the image shows i have a map of |string, MAP|
and the second map needs to be of |string,campaign| in the first instance and in the second instance |string,task| however i can only implement one or the other but not both using syntax like |string,Map|string,campaign|| or 
|string,Map|string,task||

Answer (score 0):

You have a mixed obj type map. In this case, you can use `Map<string, Map<string, any>>>`.

Alternatively, you can create a more generic type for the properties that `Task` and `Campaign` share, and use that as your type.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to create a Union Type that includes both campaign and task. Then assign that type to the Map.

```
type unionType = Campaign | Task;
let map = Immutable.Map<string, unionType>;
```

[Advanced Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html)